Is this a good way to keep users logged in after refreshing page
I am building a review posting app using the MERN stack and I was just wondering what the best and most secure way to keep users logged in. I am currently sending a jwt token in a cookie with the headers sameSite: "None", secure: true, domain : ..., that contains the users name (which shouldnt be shown for privacy sake) and the user id. Is this a safe method or should I use local storage?
I am also not using the httpsOnly header because I am signing the user back in after every refresh using the cookie in my frontend. Is this also a privacy issue and what other ways is there to keep the user signed in?
